# Migrating from TFS to Azure Devops - how to change application id in old collections?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm migrating from TFS to Azure Devops Server 2019 and I already restored my data, but when I try to attach a collection, I was told that I need to change the `ApplicationId` in the old collection, but how can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I, apparently had bad versions of everything e.g I used SQL Express (first mistake) which wasted me so much time because of tricky error messages :P and then I just had to get exact update of TFS 2015. Problem seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to installing or upgrading an Azure DevOps deployment, I suggest you first review the requirements provided in this article: [Requirements for Azure DevOps on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops)

It includes supported server operating systems and SQL versions and hardware.

---

You may have two of the same server IDs (applicationID)s

You can find your old Team Foundation Server **GUID** Info in below location:

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 1x.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config
```

There should be a value like

[image]

Then you could compare the GUID of two servers old tfs and new Azure DevOPS, change one of them and re-register db. You may need to restart sever, tfs service.

More details about it, please take a look at this blog: [How to find Team Foundation Server(TFS) GUID Info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2014/04/07/how-to-find-team-foundation-servertfs-2012-guid-info/)

Answer (score 0):

On the old (source) server, open IIS. Navigate to "tfs" and click on Application Settings. Get the value of the "applicationId" setting--you'll need this for later on the new (target) server. If you don't have recent (or recent enough) database backups of [Tfs_Configuration] and [Tfs_DefaultCollection], create them now. After the backups are done, I suggest taking the two databases offline.

On the new (target) server, restore the backups of [Tfs_Configuration] and [Tfs_DefaultCollection] from the old (source) server. You'll be overwriting the existing databases. (You should have previously backed them up, as mentioned above.) After the restores are finished, open IIS. Navigate to "tfs", open Application Settings, and double-click the "applicationId" setting. Replace the value with the applicationId from the old (source) server.

As a result of overwriting the [Tfs_Configuration] database, the TFS Notification URL and/or Server URL may be wrong. Open TSF Admin Console, navigate to the Application Tier, and click Change URLs. Change either (or both) URLs, as needed. Be sure to test them, too. (An IIS reset may be necessary before or after this step.)

Now open Visual Studio and connect to TFS.

Comment: Isn't it possible to change some records in those databases that refer to old Id?